# asp.net FileUpload doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, file-upload, updatepanel

I have `asp:FileUpload` ,  two `asp:Button` ,  and `GridView` in `UpldatePanel`.

```
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fileExcelUpload" />

<asp:Button  ID="btnShow" runat="server" Width="80px" OnClick="btnShow_Clicked"
                        AutoPostBack="true" Text="Save"/>
<asp:Button  ID="btnImport" runat="server" Width="80px" OnClick="btnImport_Clicked"
                        AutoPostBack="true" Text="Save"/>


<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
.........GridView...........
</ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnShow" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnImport" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Firstly , I retrieve some data from database and bind to `gridView` using `btnShow`.It works perfectly.
But when I upload Excel file with `asp:FileUpload` and click `btnImport` ,

```
   protected void btnImport_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (fileUExcelUpload.HasFile)
            { 
            .....
            }
    }
```

the boolean value `fileUExcelUpload.HasFile` return `False` .
But when I remove `<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnImport" EventName="Click" />` from UpldatePanel's triggers , it return `True` .

(The reason why I add `btnImport`'s Click event to UpdatePanel's Triggers is , I want to persist Uploaded File of `asp:FileUpload` after postback . )
Is there any right way to do it ? Kindly help me Please :) Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in the

```
<Triggers> </Triggers>

<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpload" />
```

here btnUpload is the id of the fileupload control

Comment: Server Error : Control with ID 'fileExcelUpload' being registered through RegisterAsyncPostBackControl or RegisterPostBackControl must implement either INamingContainer, IPostBackDataHandler, or IPostBackEventHandler.

Comment: Remove "<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnImport" EventName="Click" />" and try to add just <asp:PostBackTrigger ..../>

Comment: make sure you keep the fileupload control inside the content template